# Service Worker not working with external resources

Tags: javascript

I have a website where I configured a service worker. Everything works fine, except when I try to load external resources (like JS/CSS from a CDN). The browser says:

`The FetchEvent for "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().`

After Googling a lot, some people told me to use 'no-cors' headers. I tried using it, but the same error still happens. Here is my service worker which fetches the content using the `no-cors` method.

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    
    event.respondWith((async () => {
    
            const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request,{mode:"no-cors"});

            if (fetchResponse.ok) {
                
                return fetchResponse;
                
            }   
    
    })());
  
});
```

I dont have control over CORS headers in the responses from the CDN and for several reasons I cant serve those remote files locally from my server. So how do I fetch those requests and make it work? I am not even asking about caching, at this point I even disabled caching in the server worker, I am first just trying to make the `fetch` above work without triggering an error.

Comment: If `event.respondWith` is failing, it seems likely that your `fetchResponse` is not `ok` or that the fetch is failing for some other reason. Have you tried checking the dev tools console for errors? Have you tried using a debugger or `console.log` to see what `response.ok` evaluates to?

Comment: @JoshKelley The response is working correctly because all requests (made to the same origin of my website) work fine. Only the external requests fail with the same error.